# How to get the current version of a node?

Tags: 7

I programmaly want to set the current version of a node to a status in workbench "needs_review" however the current version of the node is not the published version of the node.

```
$vid  
5000 = Published 
4999 = Current revision
```

How to get the versionid of a node which contains the current version?

I tried several and I guess:

```
$vid = revisioning_get_latest_revision_id ($nodeid)
$node = node_load ($nodeid, $vid)
```

but this is of course giving an error as a answer as I'm using D7, the function revisioning_get_latest_revision_id cannot be found.

I also saw https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_revision_list/7.x
But do not understand how the get the current revision of the node.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need it. It is included in the node structure under value:

```
$node->workbench_moderation['current']->vid
```